# How to invalidate that which column having data type mismatch and also ORA-01722 while insert data into table from one user to another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with some records in one user and another table with empty records. I want to migrate the data of that table from one ***user*** to ***another*** but I got one error **ORA: 01722** because the datatype of the target table is slightly mismatch. What should I do resolve this problem without changes the datatype.
Data type of the source table is-

[image: Description of the source table]

Description of the target table-

[image: Description of the target table]

In both table in different user only one column is mismatch datatype ***LOTFRONTAGE***. In source table datatype is **varchar2** and in target table datatype is **Number**.
How to invalidate that which column having data type mismatch

While I insert the data using this SQL query-

```
insert into md.house(ID,MSSUBCLASS,MSZONING,
CAST(LOTFRONTAGE AS VARCHAR2(15)),LOTAREA,LOTSHAPE,LOTCONFIG,
NEIGHBORHOOD,CONDITION1,BLDGTYPE,OVERALLQUAL,
YEARBUILT,ROOFSTYLE,EXTERIOR1ST,MASVNRAREA)
select ID,MSSUBCLASS,MSZONING,LOTFRONTAGE,
LOTAREA,LOTSHAPE,LOTCONFIG,NEIGHBORHOOD,CONDITION1,
BLDGTYPE,OVERALLQUAL,YEARBUILT,ROOFSTYLE,
EXTERIOR1ST,MASVNRAREA from SYS.HOUSE_DATA;
```

Then i got an error

```
ORA-00917: comma missing
```

Comment: First task you can do is to post the table DDL here and secondly what vaules you are trying to insert

Comment: You're trying to insert a string into a column which has data type of `NUMBER`. You need to ensure that the values which are going into the destination column are of Numeric values.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: `cast` inside the column list of the insert statement makes no sense. You need to cast in the **SELECT** part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i try but again give error ORA-01722: invalid number, means when i use CAST in select then it generates error. What should i do to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
INSERT INTO 2ndTable  (ID,...,LOTFRONTAGE,....MASVNAREA)
       SELECT ID,...,to_number(LOTFRONTAGE),....MASVNAREA
       FROM 1stTable;
```